# Why are multiple rows not being saved in db when reading file?

Tags: java, android

I have this snippet here:

```
    try {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/information.csv");
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        boolean firstLine = true;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println("Print the contents from the file :" + line);

            if (firstLine) {
                firstLine = false;
                continue;

            } else {

                    //deserialize the string to Object
                    TransferData tdBack = TransferData.fromString(line));

                    //Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                    for (Collection collection : tdBack.getCollections()) {

                        values.put("reminders", collection.getReminders());
                        values.put("region", collection.getRegion().getId());
                        values.put("collection", collection.getCollection());
                        values.put("collection_interval", collection.getCollectionInterval().getId());

                    }

                    //insert the new row
                    sqLiteDatabase.insert(COLLECTION_TABLE, null, values);
                    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("Select * FROM collection", null);
                    Log.d("MainActivity", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
```

However, even though I have at least two rows with data in my file, it only saves the first row of information in my file. I don't know why it doesn't read my whole file and save both rows of data into the database?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `insert()` inside the `for` loop where you iterate your collections.

Currently you're only inserting the values from the last iteration of the loop.